# Parse Query Missing Values

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I'm running a query to fetch all objects that are contained in the `objectStrings` but not all objects returned in the query.

```
var queryRestaurants = PFQuery(className: "Restaurant")
            queryRestaurants.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: objectStrings)
            queryRestaurants.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objectsRestaurants: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if objectsRestaurants!.isEmpty { //if objects != nil {
                    println("ERROR, NO RESULTS")
                } else {
                    restaurantArray = objectsRestaurants!
                    println(objectsRestaurants)
}
```

I double checked my backend and the objectIds in `objectStrings` are valid.
Example of what objectStrings looks like:

```
var objectStrings = [7US4aCNtae, odRzaG2zPn, T3QPXn8fvi, B4UDIKfR2t, ScuShpQbj2]
```

Why is Parse not fetching every object with objectIds contained in `objectStrings`? Only some of them are returned.

#### Update:

After many tests, i found that if I remove `B4UDIKfR2t`, all the values can be found. Once I add it back, some objects are missing again. But there's nothing different about `B4UDIKfR2t` and it can be fetched on its own just fine.

I just tried fetching only `B4UDIKfR2t` and the value that is missing `odRzaG2zPn`. They both are fetched successfully when its just the two of them.

Any idea what the problem is here?

Comment: have you tried checking for an error? i.e. `if error != nil {println(error)}`

Comment: Because `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` runs asynchronously, is the println in your code snippet the one that you're saying doesn't print all of them? Or is it a different println?

Comment: @user3498976 i just checked for errors. there are none.

Comment: @rb612 Yes `println(objectsRestaurants)` is missing some objects that are listed in `objectStrings`

Comment: try to remove the space between the object id and the comma. With objects are been retrieved and with ones are not?

Comment: @icaro i'm using a much larger list of objectIds. but in the list above, only `odRzaG2zPn` is missing. it doesn't seem to be a problem with spacing (other objects are found)

Comment: Also, you don't have each element in the example `objectStrings` wrapped in a string. Do you have them in your code?

Comment: @rb612 yes they are strings. I was just pasting the console output.

Comment: Try to retrieve just the odRzaG2zPn, maybe there is something wrong with the record in that case

Comment: @Icaro oddly enough, I tried to retrieve just `odRzaG2zPn` and it worked. I also tried adding a few other objectIds in and it worked.

Comment: @icaro After many tests, i found that if I remove `B4UDIKfR2t`, all the values can be found. Once I add it back, some objects are missing again. But there's nothing different about `B4UDIKfR2t`.

Comment: Could you give the definition of `restaurantArray` ? Where it is defined?

Comment: @renzo yes, its defined further up `var restaurantArray: [AnyObject] = []`. It is just an empty array. But the issue occurs when I try printing `objectsRestaurants`.